# Save multipe forms to localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

How do I use localStorage like you insert a new row into a database?
I have a form and upon submitting, the form values are saved into the localStorage. 
I refresh the page, I fill out the form again and click submit and save the values to my localStorage again. 
I do this multiple times.

How do I save the form values without overwriting them? I want the localStorage save the form like you insert a new value to a database.

```
form[0]
   name: "jane"
form[1]
   name: "john"
form[2]:
   name: "joe"
```

Comment: Though I have never used it but ***[`this(IndexedDB)`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325135/Getting-Started-with-IndexedDB)*** might solve your problem... I guess..!!

Answer (score 0):

I'n not quite sure why you would like to do this, but you can do the following.

You can serialize the form and store the rsult. LocalStorage are just, like cookies, key: value pairs. You can do it like:

```
localStorage.setItem("form_1", {name: "jane"});
```

You can repeat this for every submit.
Fetching the data goes like:

```
localStorage.getItem("form_1");
```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript array to keep track of forms. For example:

```
var formValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.formValues);
// When you submit add to form values
formValues.push({ /* Form data */ });
localStorage.formValues = JSON.stringify(formValues);
```

To retrieve a value use `formValues[formIndex]`.

Js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/3ZHqH/